# SharePoint hybrid and Microsoft On-Premises data gateway

Tags: sharepoint-server, flow, hybrid

In our environment we are not the tenant owners and we don't even have sharepoint admin permissions. But we are farm admins of the on-prem SharePoint 2019 environment. What kind of permissions from tenants are required to setup on-premises data gateway to consume power app platform like flow and powerapps . Where do the gateway need to be installed  ? I have googled and I didn't find much information.

Answer (score 2):

The Data Management Gateway should be installed on it's own server (or >1 as it supports HA). You would need Power BI Administrator rights to deploy it. From there, you can add one or more individuals to administer the gateway in the Power BI portal. These admins would have the ability to manage the Gateway in Power BI, including removing the Gateway, add/edit/delete Gateway connections, and add other administrators.

The Gateway does require Flow P1 licensing to use with Flow (same with PowerApps, but there is no direct PowerApps integration with on-prem, you'd have to initiate the usage of the PowerApps from the PowerApps portal).

Comment: How does the SharePoint server trust it , since we are installing on the standalone server . And for powerapps , in general, how does the users acess it in the hybrid environment ? Hybrid is only get the data from the on-prem lists .

Comment: It is trusted by virtue of the account used to make the connection back to on-prem SharePoint via the Gateway (this is an option for each Flow Action/Trigger you need to set). PowerApps will need to be accessed via the PowerApps mobile app or powerapps.microsoft.com -- there is no integration with SharePoint on-prem.

Comment: Thanks Trevor . This is very helpful.